# Combine between and like in Spring Data JPA

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I want to create query to find all rows in a PostgreSQL table where a column value is between a pair of dates and another column value is like a keyword using Spring Data JPA.

Need to find records in table mapped to entity `Student` where `dob` is between `from` and `to` and `name` like `keyword`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the HQL:

```
from Student s where s.name like :keyword and s.dob between :from and :to
```

`:keyword`, `:from` and `:to` are parameters of the query